# Firebug Lite on IE loads from remote site, but loading from local site has problems

Tags: browser, race-condition, firebug-lite

This is true for IE 7, 8, and 9.  The page

http://www.topics2look.com/code-examples/firebug-lite-race-condition/using-remote-firebug-lite-js-file.html

loads Firebug Lite's JS file remotely, and it almost always load successfully on IE 8 (on a Virtual PC).   (it is loading from https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js)

But if the JS file is copied locally and linked locally (on the same server as the HTML), then sometimes the page can load with Firebug Lite, sometimes there is an error.

http://www.topics2look.com/code-examples/firebug-lite-race-condition/

(Trying reloading the above page several times and see if you see that same behavior).  Does someone know what is making it happen and how to prevent it from happening?  (actually, on IE 9, it never loads successfully)  (this question aims to understand webpage rendering and Javascript loading of web programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem. It seems to have something to do with the `document.domain` property and JavaScripts "[same origin policy.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)" See this blog post:

http://ianlotinsky.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/document-domain/

I've found that, when opening a local HTML file, Firebug Lite will work fine if loaded from the server (ie, using https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js).